# Gradle Could not HEAD https://..pom > peer not authenticated

Tags: https, gradle, maven-central

When you upgrade from gradle 2.0 to 2.1, you may see following error.

```
Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/1.0/gradle-download-task-1.0.pom'.
         > peer not authenticated
```

To be fair, this error is not due to gradle. It is problem of how java handles ssl connections.

I am using following java version.

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

You can use [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse) to import security certificate your java installation.

I do not care about https downloads, http is enough for me. So see my answer.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Change your repository syntax to one of the following

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}


repositories {
    maven  {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}
```

[Current (2.1) gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) claims that

```
Warning: Be aware that the central Maven 2 repository is HTTP only 
and HTTPS is not supported. If you need a public HTTPS enabled 
central repository, you can use the JCenter public repository 
(see Section 51.6.3, “Maven JCenter repository”).
```

I think maven central went for https. If I use following syntax.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I get following error.

> D:\tools\gradle-2.1-bin\bin\gradle.bat -q
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'XXXX'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not resolve de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:1.0.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          :XXXX:unspecified
>   >     Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/1.0/gradle-download-task-1.0.pom'.
>   >     peer not authenticated
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Actually this blog post is interesting:  https://blog.gradle.org/unable-to-download-maven-central-bintray (This is not my blog).

Answer (score 12):

**Solution 4 “Peer Not Authenticated” while adding maven "jitpack.io" in app's gradle.build.**

Simple solution is install java 8 if you have lower version. We tried with Oracle java8 and it works. :)

Note : Tried a lot of solutions those are on stackoverflow.com but none of them work for me.

Comment: I have same issue but not resolving after install java 8. any help would be appreciating

Comment: I would say, one of the most typical solutions for this problems is to update the Java Version. In my case, I switched from AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.2 to 11.0.10, which solved this problem for me

Answer (score 4):

I've updated the gradle wrapper to version 2.4, by changing the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-bin.zip
```

to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-bin.zip
```

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Travis and updating gradle version (I was using gradle wrapper) solved. I was using Gradle 2.7, then I put this on `build.gradle`:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "2.12"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case , I was using VPN and this was causing the issue . I turned off the VPN and the issue was resolved . Hope this might help anyone