# How to fix error when building an .aar

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, github

I am trying to create an .aar by following the instructions on https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android however i am running in to a big list of errors.

---

These went smoothly ofcourse

```
git clone https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android.git
cd pd-for-android
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And on the windows command prompt

```
C:\Users\New folder\pd-for-android>gradlew PdCore:assembleRelease
```

---

The errors are

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'pd-for-android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
 Required by:
      :pd-for-android:unspecified
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools
/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build
/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'. 
      > peer not authenticated
> Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3.
Required by:
      :pd-for-android:unspecified
> Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3.
> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcende
nts/android-maven-gradle-plugin/1.3/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.3.pom'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcendents/a
ndroid-maven-gradle-plugin/1.3/android-maven-gradle-plugin-1.3.pom'.
      > peer not authenticated
> Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4.
Required by:
       :pd-for-android:unspecified
> Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4.
> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray
/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.4/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.4.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradl
e/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.4/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.4.pom'.
      > peer not authenticated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.752 secs
```

---

I have little experience with maven and i need the aar for a project

Comment: Are you behind a firewall and/or proxy by any chance?

Comment: what about `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'`

Comment: No just the windows firewall if that counts @OrkunKoçyiğit

Comment: That didn't work :( @IntelliJAmiya > Whatever the problem is i don't think it has to do with the gradle version i'm using

Comment: There is a problem with the ssl in jcenter. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675814/gradle-could-not-head-https-pom-peer-not-authenticated. @IntelliJAmiya In my opinion using an alpha release of the gradle plugin is not a good practice. It is not stable.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Okay sir .

Comment: Yes, that solved the issues with unauthenticated peers. Thanks @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the .aar of pd-for-android you can simply download it from JCenter directly:

https://bintray.com/artifact/download/pd-for-android/maven/org/puredata/android/pd-core/1.0.0/pd-core-1.0.0.aar