# Peer not authenticated errors with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I've been using gradle for some time without issue but a few specific repositories fail with a `peer not authenticated` error.

I don't know what the cause is - they have valid, up to date certificates. I've tried following instructions to manually import the certificates but a) Mac has defaulted the keystore perms so they require sudo and b) one of these repos is behind cloudflare which doesn't work with the openssl download cert command.

Is there any other way to determine the cause of this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675814/gradle-could-not-head-https-pom-peer-not-authenticated

Comment: are you behind a corp proxy?

Comment: No proxy, at home on a personal computer.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Niether of the solutions on that question apply to me - I'm not using jcentral or the gradle wrapper. I tried changing to `http` instead of `https` just in case but am getting the same error. `Could not GET 'http://pex-repo.aoeu.xyz/ninja/leaping/permissionsex/permissionsex-sponge/2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
            > peer not authenticated`