# Learning Gradle but getting the following error on workstation

Tags: java, gradle

I am learning gradle and I am having issues..

I am using **https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-gradle.git** as my learning project and I goto

cd in gs-gradle/complete

then I run `gradle run` and I am getting the following error:

```
$ gradle build
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve joda-time:joda-time:2.2.
  Required by:
      :complete:unspecified
   > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.2/joda-
time-2.2.pom'.
      > peer not authenticated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.452 secs
```

Comment: Try using the gradle wrapper instead - ./gradlew run

Comment: Does it help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of `joda-time`. The current version is `2.10.5`.
In `build.gradle` change the `dependency` to point to `compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.10.5"`