# Error:(23, 13) Failed to resolve: com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

My project was working fine but when I reinstalled android studio I am having errors in importing butterknife and sdp libraries. This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.works.vipul.brainturner"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
}
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2.
     Required by:
         BrainTurner:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/intuit/sdp/sdp-android/1.0.2/sdp-android-1.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/intuit/sdp/sdp-android/1.0.2/sdp-android-1.0.2.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1.
     Required by:
         BrainTurner:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/butterknife/7.0.1/butterknife-7.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/butterknife/7.0.1/butterknife-7.0.1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peer not authenticated while importing Gradle project in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: how to resolve this issue kindly suggest

Comment: I am not able to import any 3rd party library in android studio. I am getting error anroid (23,13)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that jcenter has an invalid ssl.

As workaround try to add this to `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter {
         url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
```

Comment: I added  the above to the project gradle but still got the same error

Comment: kindly suggest a solution

Comment: Error:(23, 13) Failed to resolve: com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2

Comment: Some proxy to config?

Comment: I am using gradle-2.8. no 3rd party library is getting resolved by gradle

Comment: @vipulbansal  Check the updated answer. It uses as repo mavenCentral and the http over jcenter. Pay attention to not refer only the repo in the buildscript block.

Comment: used it but to no avail I am deeply distressed

Comment: Hi gabriele. It worked but i had to write what you suggested in project build gradle in all projects repositry but can u pls tell what is causing this problem and this seems a temporary solution. can u suggest a permanent fix?

Comment: In general repositories {
    jcenter()} should work. The ssl issue should be temporary

Comment: so will it get resoved by itself?