# Android Studio Gradle Project Refresh Failed Cause:Peer not authenticated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've searched for similar issues, but this is odd as it works perfectly for myself logged into the PC (application runs/displays on AVDs etc), but when other users log on, they get the error.
The error is:
Gradle 'AppName' project refresh failed
Error: Cause: peer not authenticated
It suggests looking at the log, of which the contents I am happy to include if it is of any help, s please ask if this will be helpful.
Each user follows the steps to switch the Sdk folder to a local drive (as studio always defaults to the users network app data folder) and all open the same source folder (again, on a local drive). I set up a environmental variable 'ANDROID_SDK_HOME' with the location of the local folder, and have successfully downloaded all the SDKs and AVDs required to the local folder. As soon as another user logs in to the same PC, sets the SDK location within settings and opens the project, the indexing completes but the Gradle build fails.
I've tried temporarily switching from https to http in the properties file, and invalidating cache and restarting but they make no difference. In all cases, it works for myself, but not for the other users. All users have been given admin rights on the PC, and are able to access the internet without issue, and have both downloaded SDK/image versions but cannot complete the build.
Can anyone shed any light as to why it works for myself but not others?
Many thanks

Comment: It should depend by the jcenter repo. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460726/error23-13-failed-to-resolve-com-intuit-sdpsdp-android1-0-2/33461117#33461117

Comment: @MartinS please do post the full error from `gradle build --stacktrace`.  This would give us a better understanding of the problem

Comment: Also consider about proxy error, if you are using proxy, so config it follow `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy`

Comment: Thanks, but surely it would not work for any of us if the proxy wasn't configured? The proxy settings are set as 'No proxy' for all users. If another user logs on and I then run android studio under my credentials, it works without issue, so it must be something specific to my profile. I'm waiting to get access to the machine (it's being used at present) and will post the log data as soon as I can.

Comment: Here's the [log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2r4fwbo63csg68/idea.log?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

change: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**1.0.0**'

to: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**2.1.0**'

Maybe helpful.