# error while importing parse project in studio peer not authenticated on parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I got error when I imported parse project file in android studio. 
Error:Cause: peer not authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Open /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
>
> Change 'https' to 'http' in the distributionUrl:
>
> distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip
>
> Then you need to sync project with gradle files

If that doesn't help, refer to this: [Peer not authenticated while importing Gradle project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse).