# Cordova build - Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, gradle, java

After upgrading the cordova and the npm of my machine (Ubuntu 15.10) I can not build a new project with the cordova. The build accuses an error in graddle.
I did some research and found some possible solutions. Solutions like changing the version and url graddle repo. Anyway, it did not work.
I am using the cordova 6.0.0 and npm 1.4.21.
Below commands of fresh cordova app installation:

```
soufraz@atlantis:~/Projects/apps$ cordova create test com.somename.test Test
Creating a new cordova project.
soufraz@atlantis:~/Projects/apps$ cd test/
soufraz@atlantis:~/Projects/apps/test$ cordova platform add android
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.somename.test
    Name: Test
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-23
Android project created with cordova-android@5.1.0
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Installing to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

soufraz@atlantis:~/Projects/apps/test$ cordova build
ANDROID_HOME=/home/soufraz/Install/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.769 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /home/soufraz/Projects/apps/test/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/soufraz/Projects/apps/test/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/soufraz/Projects/apps/test/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/soufraz/Projects/apps/test/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Extra informations:
- I have all android apis 19 - 24 installed.
- `cordova build android -- --ant` doesn't works too
- I've tested it with the java jdk 1.7 and 1.8
- All tries with --stacktrace/--debug/--info: [pastebin.com/nD6GNkbR](http://pastebin.com/nD6GNkbR)

check_reqs (it was asked via comments):

```
soufraz@atlantis:~/Projects/apps/test/platforms/android/cordova$ ./check_reqs 
ANDROID_HOME=/home/soufraz/Install/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!
```

java -version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Comment: "cordova platform update android" made no difference

Comment: I need to put some extra information or configuration to clarify my question??

Comment: "* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output."

Comment: The first things that I did. I got exactly the same output.

Comment: Almost the same thing. All tries: http://pastebin.com/nD6GNkbR

Comment: Do you have the Android SDK build tools version 23 installed? Maybe you can check the version of the different components in the SDK mlanager? In my SDK manager I see SDK build tools installed in versions 23.0.1 and 23.0.2

Comment: and you can also try to run check_reqs (should be in the platforms/android/cordova folder of your project)

Comment: @QuickFix check_reqs was posted at the end of post

Comment: @QuickFix I have the versions 23.0.1, 23.0.2, 23.1 installed

Comment: Ok, so looking more closely at the message you have when building, I think there is a SSL issue when graddle tries to retrieve the android build tools. I think it's something to do with the CA of the maven repository seen as invalid in your jvm (there's an other SO issue about a user having similar issue with linux+openjdk 8). Any chance you could install sun JVM? Or you could try to add the CA to your JVM truststore...

Comment: Could you indicate the exact version of openjdk you're using? (java -version)

Comment: java -version int the end of post

Comment: You said that you updated npm, but that isn't latest, I have 2.14.7 installed. You might need to update android tools, library support, etc. Run this `android update sdk --no-ui --filter "extra"`

Comment: "There is nothing to install or update." command output

Comment: Any solution for this error? i m getting the same. can't resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After nearly two weeks looking for a solution, I found a glorious question WITH A REAL ANSWER that solved the problem!!

Source: [Peer not authenticated while importing Gradle project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse)

**REPLICATING THE ORIGINAL ANSWER**
If you get any other error like this:

```
 Could not GET 'https://some_server.com/some/path/some.pom'.
     > peer not authenticated
```

Then you need to import a certificate:

- open the 'https://some_server.com/some/path/some.pom' in your favorite browser
- export the cert using the [Steps to export cert from a web site](http://docs.bvstools.com/home/ssl-documentation/exporting-certificate-authorities-cas-from-a-website)
- copy the cer into `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security` folder
- open a shell and go to  `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security` folder
- then import the cer into java using the

> ```
> keytool -import -alias <the short name of the server> -file <cert_file_name_you_exported.cer> -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
> ```

It will prompt you to import the certificate, type yes and press enter.

Then restart your eclipse and try building the project.

Comment: I had this issue with a brand new Ionic app, and updating Android SDK did not fix the issue for the Ionic CLI. This did the trick. You can also use the command `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:443 -showcerts` to extract the certs.

Answer (score 0):

Thats happens when you try to update your SKD or cordova without the other, then, the versions could be not compatibles (not in all the cases, but happens).
Then, try to update manually your Android SDK version and your cordova to the lastest version.

If you are using the terminal, you can use the command: `android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra`

But my recomendation is update your Android SDK

Comment: I reinstalled the android sdk from scratch. Same error.