# How do I change the default jcenter() value in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

See SO: [Peer not authenticated while importing Gradle project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse)

To eliminate errors, in new Android Studio projects I must edit build.gradle as follows:

```
    //jcenter()
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
```

The original jcenter() must be commented out. Surely there's a place to change the default value somewhere so it is no longer necessary to change each project in this manner.

Comment: I placed a question as a comment in the referenced SO posting and no one ever answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a vbscript file to do this, pasted below, and processed the following path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins

No more problem with jcenter when creating a new project.

```
const ToRead = 1
const ToWrite = 2
const ToAppend = 8
edit_path = ""
if wscript.arguments.count > 0 then edit_path = trim(wscript.arguments.item(0))
if left(edit_path,1) = """" then edit_path = mid(edit_path,2)
if right(edit_path,1) = """" then edit_path = left(edit_path,len(edit_path)-1)
if len(edit_path) = 0 then
  msgbox "Drag and drop the folder onto this script file to process it"
  wscript.quit
  end if
set fso = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim reader,writer
if not fso.folderexists(edit_path) then
  msgbox "folder not found"
  wscript.quit
  end if
count = 0
if msgbox("The following path will be processed" & vbcrlf & _
          edit_path & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
          "Continue?",vbyesno) = vbyes then
  scan edit_path
  msgbox count & " files edited"
  end if

sub scan(path)
  set files = fso.getfolder(path).files
  for each f in files
    if lcase(right(f.name,11)) = ".gradle.ftl" then edit_file path & "\" & f.name
  next
  set folders = fso.getfolder(path).subfolders
  for each f in folders : scan path & "\" & f.name : next
end sub

sub edit_file(file_name)
  set reader = fso.opentextfile(file_name,ToRead)
  a = ""
  if not reader.atendofstream then a = reader.readall
  reader.close
  found = false
  sw = true
  while sw
    sw = false
    p = instr(1,a,"  jcenter()" & vblf,vbtextcompare)
    if p > 0 then
      q = instrrev(a,vblf,p)
      if q > 0 then
        sw = true
        found = true
        spacing = p - q + 1
        a = left(a,q) & space(spacing) & "//jcenter()" & vblf & _
                        space(spacing) & "jcenter {" & vblf & _
                        space(spacing) & "    url ""http://jcenter.bintray.com/""" & vblf & _
                        space(spacing) & "}" & mid(a,p+11)
        end if
      end if
    wend
  if found then
    count = count + 1
    fso.movefile file_name,file_name & ".save"
    set writer = fso.createtextfile(file_name)
    writer.write a
    writer.close
    end if
end sub
```