# How to resolve android gradle build error?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle, build

I get the following error whenever I try to build android using cordova or android studio:

```css
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,..\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebu
g -b..\platform
s\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

```css
Information:Gradle tasks [:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources, :CordovaLib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :CordovaLib:mockableAndroidJar, :CordovaLib:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :generateDebugSources, :mockableAndroidJar, :prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not download support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.aar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.aar'.
         > peer not authenticated
```

build.gradle:

```css
/*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
*/

// GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!

apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
   }

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.8'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/mobility-barcodescanner.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode") + "0")
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
      def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peer not authenticated while importing Gradle project in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: @user13 Its not about .pom, but .aar, how to resolve it?

Comment: it is unable to download that library version check your speed of internet

Answer (score 2):

There can be two reasons

1. Most likely you have an **older version** of this library and in build file you are **using new one** .So try this ,

   go to project structure => dependency => library dependency and add the one you have and remove the previous one.
2. Your **`SDK`** don't have this dependency and studio is **trying to download** it so let it happen because it is an important library to support old android device platform.

Comment: It says could not download, how do I let it download?

Comment: it's indicating something wrong with gradle configuration file.check the link below
[https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html]

Answer (score 1):

It needs to download that library in order to **do your build**, but you've put Android Studio into offline mode.

To fix it, go to `Preferences > Gradle and ensure that the "Offline work"` checkbox is not checked.

> Go to Setting -->> Search Gradle -->> Click gradle -->> Uncheck Offline
>   Work

check below image

https://snag.gy/afNm9A.jpg

Comment: I do not see an option prefernecs in studio!

Comment: i have got this link, check http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have: (in your build.gradle main setting project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check you `build.gradle` to downgrade your SDK version, if you need this version in particular just download it and Sync.

Comment: Where can i do that?

Comment: you can see it under app>build.gradle

Comment: Before you change it check witch version of SDK you use in your project

Comment: I am using 24, but its not seen in my build.gradle

Comment: Look if you choose to open your project with `Project ` you will see it under  app with the name  `build.gradle ` if you choose to open your project with  `Android ` you will see it under  `Gradle Scripts`  and the name is  `build.gradle(Module:app)`, I hope i was clear.