# java 6 -> mongodb maven dependency error: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, ssl, gradle

Ok, I have a java 6 project , in mac high sierra, project with a mongo dependency.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.14.3'
}
```

I get an ssl error when building it using gradle as follows:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.

  > Could not resolve org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.14.3.
  >   Required by:
  >     :buildSrc:unspecified
  >   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.14.3/mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.pom'.
  >   peer not authenticated

org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
    ...

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.14.3/mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.pom'.
    ...

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)

I tried importing the security certificate into the cacerts but this didn't do it.

```
#from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home//lib/security/
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect repo1.maven.org:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mavencert.pem
# from ~
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias mavencert -keystore cacerts -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/mavencert.pem
# enter password: changeit
```

Upgrading to a never version of java is not a posiblity.
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peer not authenticated while importing Gradle project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: We don't need all those lines of the error message, please edit it down to have only the essential information (Just the first few lines probably).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection to https://repo1.maven.org using Java 6 fails because of the Java version you have installed does not support TLS1.2 and repo1.maven.org only [supports TLS 1.2](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=repo1.maven.org) connections.

If you really want to continue using Java 6 you need to install Java SE Development Kit 6, Update 111 or newer.

IMHO you should delete Java 6 (it is outdated and insecure) and install a current Oracle Java version. I assume your version is the one provided by Apple - AFAIK Apple has stopped support for their Java version. Therefore you should no longer use it.

Comment: switching to a jave 6 version with TLS1.2 enabled did the trick; jdk1.6.0_191